VBA Runtime Error -2147467259(80004005) while using "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" to read CSV file
I am using a Win11(Language=Japanese) Laptop with Office LTSC 2021 installed.
I've written enclosed VBA Code to convert a csv file into excel(xlsx) file.
There is error message popping-up when performing "conn.Open strUTF8Conn", mentioning "VBA Runtime Error -2147467259(80004005)"sorts of messages.
Sub ImportCSVtoExcel()
    Dim fd As FileDialog
    Dim strFilePath As String
    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rs As Object
    Dim strQuery As String
    Dim strUTF8Conn As String
    
    ' Create Dialogue Box for CSV file selection
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.Filters.Clear
    fd.Filters.Add "CSV Files", "*.csv"
    fd.Title = "Please choose your CSV file"
    
    ' Display Dialog Window
    If fd.Show = -1 Then
        strFilePath = fd.SelectedItems(1)
    Else
        MsgBox "No files have been selected!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Create ADO Connection OBject
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    ' Set the text into UTF-8 code
        strUTF8Conn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & strFilePath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;"";"
    
    ' Open the UT8-8 Text File
    conn.Open strUTF8Conn
    
    ' SQL Queries
    strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [" & strFilePath & "]"
    
    ' Perform the Query and export the results into Excel
    rs.Open strQuery, conn
    Sheet1.Cells.Clear
    Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    
    ' Close all connections and clear all Objects.
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "CSV imported into Excel"
End Sub

There should be no problems with my file names or paths. What else may cause this problem and how should I correct it?

The error code is "Access Denied", but you have not shown which line of code and file is the cause. You can add some extra print statements or use the debugger to find the root cause.

I've mentioned, the error occurred when running "conn.Open strUTF8Conn"

But you have still not explained which actual file is causing the problem. What is the content of strFilePath?
